# How to determine when an action should be done after several loops

Tags: java, linked-list

So basically, I have a programming assignment, and it involves two lines at an airline, one for frequent flyers and one for regular flyers. I have a for loop set up that, each time it runs, it determines whether some amount of frequent flyers gets in, some amount of regular flyers, or no one. For a frequent flyer, it is supposed to take 3 minutes to service a flyer, with one "minute" being a single iteration of the loop. For the regular flyers, it will take 5 minutes to service one person, again, with one iteration of the loop being a single minute. How can I determine when someone in the line has been serviced? As in, how can I pull someone out of the line whenever 3 or 5 iterations of the loop have occured, respectively. I'm utilizing a linked list.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code, post it so we can see it.  If you're not sure how much you need to post, you should read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like a variation of Fizz Buzz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I think I got the idea.
You could use `break;` to exit the loop (if that's what you're trying to do), and to test the amount of times the loop has been executed, you can use an int. It will look something like this:

```
   int i = 0;
    for(initialization, condition, iteration){
    //Your code
    if(i == 3 | i == 5){
    break; //If you have your own method to "pull someone out of the line", 
           //then insert it here instead of using break, and also insert i = 0.
       }
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: This helped a lot actually! I was trying to wrap my head around how exactly to determine when they have been serviced, and this helped to make more sense of it.